# Android ICS Dialog Title Color

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-styles

I want to use a custom color for the Dialog in ICS-Devices. The default one is blue (see image), how can I set this to a color that fits my app color scheme, e.g. red ?

[image: Example dialog]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alert.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'>User Agent</font>"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
alert.getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); //This is for Color
alert.setCancelable(true);
```

Comment: This sets the background color. OP wants to change the title color.